# c++ compiling error related to constructor/destructor definition

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I'm trying to define the constructor and destructor of my class but I keep getting the error:

> definition of implicitly-declared 'x::x()'

What does it mean?

Part of the code:

```
///Constructor
StackInt::StackInt(){
    t = (-1);
    stackArray = new int[20];
};

///Destructor
StackInt::~StackInt(){
    delete[] stackArray;
}
```

Comment: How are your files structured (*.h, *.cpp)? Which file is that posted code in?

Answer (score 50):

In the class declaration (probably in a header file) you need to have something that looks like:

```
class StackInt {
public:
    StackInt();
    ~StackInt();  
}
```

To let the compiler know you don't want the default compiler-generated versions (since you're providing them).

There will probably be more to the declaration than that, but you'll need at least those - and this will get you started.

You can see this by using the very simple:

```
class X {
        public: X();   // <- remove this.
};
X::X() {};
int main (void) { X x ; return 0; }
```

Compile that and it works. Then remove the line with the comment marker and compile again. You'll see your problems appear then:

```
class X {};
X::X() {};
int main (void) { X x ; return 0; }
```

`` qq.cpp:2: error: definition of implicitly-declared `X::X()' ``

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the problem.

Comment: @MB, I was working on a test prog while you answered so I thought I'd add it rather than make a competing answer that said the same thing. Then I upvoted your much better answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is that everything that the constructor accesses must be public.  I have gotten this error before.

```
class X{
   T *data;
 public:      // <-move this to include T *
   X();
   ~X();
}
```

This code still have the error because in my constructor I had the following:

```
X::X(){data = new T();
```

Which meant that although I had made the constructor and destructor public, the data they were working with was still private, and I still got the "definition of implicitly-declared" error.

Comment: This is not correct at all. The constructor can access any private member variable, and to do so is usually much of its job.

Comment: Yes, the constructor can access any private member variable, but **only of its own class.**  This means that if your constuctor wants to access the private variables of the T *data it should be public.